# Como executar uma função apenas uma vez e interrompê-la caso ocorra um onBlur?

Tags: javascript, funções, input

Tenho dois inputs: o que é digitado no "Título" é duplicado no "Código do Material" com as devidas normalizações (i.e. conversão de espaços e remoção de caracteres). Há algum modo de - *usando JavaScript puro* - fazer com que essa "duplicação" ocorra apenas uma vez? Algo como um `onBlur` no qual se o usuário editar o campo "Código do Material" e vier a editar também o "Título", não ocorrerá mais interferências naquele, visto que esse pode ser editado pelo mesmo usuário.

Grato desde já!

```js
document.getElementById('f_titulo').addEventListener('input', duplica);

function duplica() {
      const codigomaterial = document.getElementById('f_titulo').value;
      const codigoalterado = codigomaterial.normalize('NFD').replace(/([\u0300-\u036f]|[^_0-9a-zA-Z\s])/g, '').replace(/ /g, "_").toLowerCase().substring(0, 20);
      document.getElementById('f_cod').value = codigoalterado;
};
```

```html
<input id="f_titulo" type="text" maxlength="60" placeholder="Título">

<input id="f_cod" type="text" maxlength="20" placeholder="Código do Material" required>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caros, consegui o que queria adicionando uma função ao evento `onBlur` dentro do `f_titulo`:

```
<input id="f_titulo" onBlur="once()" type="text">

    function once(){
    document.getElementById('f_titulo').removeEventListener('input', duplica);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Uma ideia que resolve o problema mas não é muito inteligente é você
> criar uma variavel global que sirva de flag
>
> chamemos essa flag de `editCodigo = true`
>
> você pode criar listener de evento para `f_cod` que ao invés de olhar
> 'input' olhe 'onblur' e este evento seta a flag `editCodigo = false`
>
> e dentro da duplicata haveria um `if(editCodigo){....}else{ /*ignora*/}`
>
> ou seja so executaria enquanto não tiver tido uma interação de input
> com `f_cod`

---

> Ao invés de usar essa abordagem da flag você pode excluir o listenner
> de  f_titulo

---

> Outra ideia é fazer todo o processo como vc ja esta fazendo porem só alterar
> `document.getElementById('f_cod').value = codigoalterado;` caso o
> f_cod.value seja igual a f_titulo.value normalizado
>
> pois se vc tem
>
> - A==a  o conteúdo da esquerda normalizado é igual a 'a' logo a função funciona
>
> porem se vc adiciona um 'b' em f_cod e depois outro 'A' em f_titulo
>
> - AA==ab   o conteúdo da esquerda normalizado seria 'aa' ....e aa"!="Ab" logo a função para de funcionar
>
> se vc corrigir a direita ou a esquerda volta a funciona
>
> - AB==ab   ou AA==aa

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, @le314u! Acabei removendo a escuta do meu evento de duplicação. Vou colocar em uma resposta à parte, mas muito obrigado pela ajuda!